# Swift code in between `#if TARGETMACRO` -> `#endif` prevents code coloring/autocomplete

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently dealing with an annoyance while developing in XCode with swift, and hoping someone can help.

My app has two targets, which we'll call: 1) ActualApp 2) iMessageApp. As expected from the names, 1) is the target for the main app, and 2) is for an iMessage app extension.

There are some swift classes that are available to both targets. Some of these classes have some code that can only available to 1) ActualApp, and shouldn't (in some cases can't) be available in 2) iMessageApp.

Currently, under my iMessageApp app target, under "Build Settings" -> "Other Swift Flags", all my configurations have "-DIMESSAGEAPP" in the list, so that I can control which code is compiled/used for my two targets like so:

```
#if IMESSAGEAPP
// Code that only works for iMessageApp target
#endif

#if !IMESSAGEAPP
// Code that only works for ActualApp target
#endif
```

This works and compiles and runs as expected, but I run into the following issues with code I write in between the `#if` and `#endif`:
1) Doesn't allow autocomplete
2) Doesn't allow XCode to color the code

Anyone have any solutions or suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Try restarting Xcode. I don't have any issues with this under Xcode 10.2.1.